# Как узнать под фокусом ли текущий input

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я прохожу по всем инпутам формы и произвожу какие-то действия над ними:

```
var form = $(this).closest('form');    
form.find('input:visible').each(function (e, input) {

}
```

Мне нужно произвести определенное действие для input который под фокусом. Как это прописать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вот [так](https://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/):

```
if ($(this).is( ":focus" )) { 
  <действие> 
}
```